# Did Lucy Heartfilia and Zeref meet before the Eclipse Gate arc?

Tags: fairy-tail

I'm currently writing a fiction about Lucy Heartfilia and Zeref. I believe that she doesn't know what he looks like and that they didn't meet during the Tenrou Island Arc but I'm not 100% sure of it.

Did they meet before the Eclipse Gate arc?

Comment: First of all are you following manga or anime, if manga then, fairy tail is finished, and i don't about anime. And for your answer i have no memory of them meeting face to face, i might be wrong though.

Comment: I'm mainly talking about the manga here though there is probably no difference between the manga and the anime when it comes to my question since there aren't any "non-canon" episode that involves Zeref before the Eclipse Gate arc.

Comment: IIRC, no they did't, at least not in Tenrou arc and as i stated above, i doubt that they actually met each other face to face in any chapter of manga

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Lucy never got the chance to look at Zeref.

Only Natsu, Elfman, Evergreen, Happy and Gray (in chapter 522, "Gray's Trump Card") have seen him. Lucy has heard of Zeref but never got a chance to see him.

However, towards the end of the manga series, Lucy *does* meet a Zeref look-a-like in chapter 545 (way after the Eclipse Gate Arc), "Friends you Can't do Without". The way he is portrayed was that he was a young writer attempting to meet with Lucy Heartfelia after her award ceremony. He picks up the handkerchief dropped by, what looks to me, Mavis Vermillion. They both engage in a conversation then leave, never to be seen for the remainder of the chapter.